# Unable to store Blob types in IndexedDB on Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, blob, indexeddb

I'm having issues with storing blobs in IndexedDB on Safari version 10.1.2 (also facing the same issue on IOS).

I'm using the angular2-indexeddb module wrapper, however - i don't think it's a problem with the module as such. My code works fine in Chrome, however when attempting to put a blob object in the Safari indexedDb, the record always displays as 'null' (see FileData field):

[image: FileData displays as 'null']

I have tried a variety of different blob files (audio, video, html) and they always display as 'null'. No (visible) errors are returned from the IndexedDb when inserting this record.

From what i've read - blobs should be supported in Safari. I'm thinking the problem could be associated with the way the blob is created? i.e. perhaps Safari does not like the blob data?

Below is a sample of my code (i haven't included too much here, so please let me know if more information is required):

```
      // create blob:
      const aFileParts = ['<a id="a"><b id="b">foo!</b></a>'];
      const oMyBlob = new Blob(aFileParts, {type : 'text/html'});

      console.log('blob type' + oMyBlob.type); // outputs as 'text/html'

      // initialize my indexeddb store:
      return this.initializeStores().then(() => {

        // add 'oMyBlob' to the FileData data store:
        return this.db.add('FileData',
          { FileName: 'foo', FileData: oMyBlob, FileType: 'audio' }).then(() => {

            // Success
            console.log('added ' + 'foo' + ' to FileData store.');

            // Get the file from the FileData store
            return this.db.getByIndex('FileData', 'FileName', 'foo').then((record) => {
              return Promise.resolve();
            });

          }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            this.handleError(error)
            return Promise.reject(error);
          });
      }, (error) => {
        this.handleError(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
```

as a side note - i can store this data as an ArrayBuffer in Safari IndexedDB without any issues. The problem is that i then have to convert this back to a blob when i retrieve it from the db (the extra processing power required is not ideal).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Last time I checked Safari did not support blobs

Comment: Well they are. I'm able to create blobs, display them as video - but not save them in an IndexedDB. Kinda strange.

Comment: Sorry. I meant to say that safaris implementation of indexeddb does not support writing or reading blobs

Comment: Do you have a source for this? i just need to completely rule it out before moving on.

Comment: The documentation states that it follows the indexeddb standards: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html - which (drilling down) states that blobs are supported.

Comment: Sorry do not recall exact source. I know it was true as some point when blob storing first came out but not sure if still true

Comment: Ok thanks. At this point i might just abandon this particular approach.

Comment: I faced a similar issue with localforage. I was able to workaround it by saving the Blobs at root of the primary_object, instead of storing it cleanly as `file` property of an deeper object. To make it work, I created an unique id that I stored in the deep object, which allowed me to retrieve the Blob at root. But that was with localforage, and I don't experience this bug anymore (not sure if it has been fixed by a Safari update or something else)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i managed to find the cause of the issue. When creating my store i was referencing an incorrect index (mainly because i was following an online tutorial)

```
const objectDataStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
    'FileData', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
```

The keypath 'id' does not exist within my store. This was causing the issues when saving the blobs (strangely with no reported error...and it didn't appear to cause issues on chrome).

The correct code:

```
const objectDataStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
    'FileData', { keyPath: 'FileName', autoIncrement: true });
```

'FileName' is the name of a property within my store object. This now fixes the issue on desktop safari. So the lesson here is to make sure the KeyPath is correct.

However, i now face a new issue. On IOS Safari the blob fails to persist to the indexedDb. I get the following error:

```
error: DOMError {name: "UnknownError", message: "An unknown error occurred within Indexed Database."}
```

So it appears that blobs are not supported for indexedDb on IOS Safari (i'm assuming this is a bug). For now i will just store ArrayBuffers instead of blobs.

Comment: Do you know if the bug still exists in iOS ?

Comment: @NeryOrtez I'm not sure, i haven't worked on this feature a for sometime now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I can confirm that on iOS Safari version 11.2.6, IndexedDB cannot store Blobs as values.

I wrote a small piece of code to store a String value and it works. If I comment out the String and replace it with a Blob, using the exact same code, Safari gives an "Unknown Error"

{name: "UnknownError", message: "An unknown error occurred within Indexed Database."}

Perhaps try to convert the Blob to an ArrayBuffer before storing it.

Comment: Thanks, but i already stated that solution in my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

I found I could get around this issue by converting the `Blob`s to base64 strings before storing them and then back again on retrieval.

This package was useful https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-blob

Answer (score 0):

If You still have a problem with indexedDb on iOS/OSX just dont use auto-incrementation, becaues it's a bug in Safari.