# iOS Workbox Background Sync - FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: UnknownError: Error preparing Blob/File data to be stored in object store

Tags: ios, offline, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a PWA that runs offline with background sync running and it works on all browsers (Brave/Safari/Chrome/Firefox tested). I am able to add articles and upon adding an article it is stored in the indexedDB. If offline and the app can't reach the server to post the data the request goes into the workbox-background-sync as expected, and the article makes its way to my MySQL database once the network becomes active again.

However, on iOS Safari, the PWA works online but when I go offline and try post an article, the data makes its way into the indexedDB successfully but the background sync isn't added to the queue and i'm presented with the error

> FetchEvent.respondWith received an error: UnknownError: Error preparing Blob/File data to be stored in object store

I'm assuming this is because the body of the request is a Blob. How would I go about storing the request and have iOS do the sync the next time the network is online?

Many thanks for any help provided.

Here are my snippets of the add article code (main.js), and my service worker code (sw.js)

```
function addAndPostArticle(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = {
    id: Date.now(),
    title: document.getElementById('article-title').value,
    content: document.getElementById('article-content').value
  };

  updateUI([data]);
  saveArticleDataLocally([data]);

  const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  const body = JSON.stringify(data);

  return fetch('/pwa/api/add.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: body
  });
}
```

sw.js

```
const bgSyncPlugin = new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('myQueueName', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
});

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  '/pwa/api/add.php',
  workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

Comment: Based from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308104/unable-to-store-blob-types-in-indexeddb-on-safari), this is a known issue about blobs are not supported for indexedDb on IOS Safari. You can try to store it to ArrayBuffers instead of blobs. But there's a supported documentation regarding [indexedDB Support for IOS Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_0.html). Therefore, it can be a bug.

Comment: hi jess, thanks for the reply, I'll have a look to see if Workbox allows the response body to be changed from blob to array buffer